# Is there any way to limit the step functions to run one after other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-steps

If I have 3 state machines running how to limit them by executing only one after other

a
b
c

After initializing the state machines I want to run b once a is successful and run c once b is successful.

Answer (score 1):

With Step Functions you can configure a State machine to run as a next state for a previous created state, so you will able to manage this creating another Step Function to handle the three ones that you already have:

[image]

To handle these states will have different Integration patterns:

- **Call and continue**
  Step Functions calls the API, receives an HTTP response, and continues to the next step.
- **Wait for child execution to complete**
  Pause the parent execution at this state and monitor the child execution. Resume the parent execution when the child execution is complete.
- **Wait for callback**
  Pause the execution at this state until the execution receives a callback from the SendTaskSuccess or SendTaskFailure APIs with the task token

In your case the best option will use the **Wait for child execution to complete** integration pattern to be sure that all child states are done inside each state machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response ,but I want to know can we stop the second execution until first one is done completely

Comment: 99e085ae-80d7-4a95-89cf-cee262c5f46c  Succeeded Feb 8, 2022 07:47:20.184 PM Feb 8, 2022 07:51:14.375 PM

2804f0a5-f59f-410c-8cea-1d844ee1cd0b  Succeeded Feb 8, 2022 06:27:52.547 PM Feb 8, 2022 06:30:55.608 PM

Comment: I want to pause these